# Selenium - show notes about what is going on in browser

Tags: django, selenium, testing

I'm working on Selenium test which simulates every User action on my website. From registration to modifying forms etc.

There are hundreds of actions so I would like to see what is currently going on. Is there a way to add some notes to Selenium so I can see them in the browser real time? For example some transparent overlay with text?

I think it is possible to create a workaround using AJAX but maybe there is something built in.

Comment: Console logging is not enough ?

Comment: Add an HTML element with Selenium that is styled as absolutely positioned on top of everything else and change its text when you need to show information. You could do this in the `setUp` method so it's setup for every test.